# Take snapshots of iterations of the Fruchterman-Reingold layout

Tags: r, igraph

I want to take some snapshot of the evolving Fruchterman-Reingold layout, to get a feeling of how the layout is evolving. First I thought I could do some steps, draw the layout, and put the already calculated positions back to the `layout.fruchterman.reingold` via the `start` argument.

It doesn't work because the initial heat can not be adjusted. Maybe the documentation lacks some information. I am using igraph version 0.7.1.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not supported by the implementation of the Fruchterman-Reingold layout in igraph. If you feel adventurous, you can tweak the source code of the C core of igraph (in particular, `src/layout.c`) to log the coordinates after each iteration in the layout, but that requires recompiling the library from scratch.